# Scrollview как убрать сверху и снизу полоски

Tags: android, xamarin

При скролле создается неприятная подсветка. Интересует как её убрать?
я думал что это делает этот атрибут `android:fillViewport="true"` но нет.
Сам axml

```
    <ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/scroll"      
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="none">
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">
  <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/login_background_dexpens" />
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:isScrollContainer="true"
      android:paddingLeft="20dp"
      android:paddingRight="20dp">
      <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:minWidth="20px"
          android:minHeight="20px"
          android:paddingLeft="20dp"
          android:paddingRight="20dp"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/logoBlock"
          android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
          android:layout_height="104.3dp">
      <ImageView
          android:src="@drawable/dexpens_logo_small"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/dexpensLogo" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/logoBlock"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/txtRegEditTextContainer">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
          app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtRegPasswordConfirm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:hint="Password Confirm"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/shared_white_color_cursor" />
      </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomBlockRegistration"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtRegEditTextContainer"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
      <Button
          android:text="@string/registration"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="40sp"
          android:id="@+id/btnReg"
          android:textSize="18dp"
          android:textColor="#fff"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:background="@drawable/shared_button_border"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установите во вложенной вьюшке:

```
android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
```

и еще попробуйте:

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="none"
```